# Can a python function be both a generator and a "non-generator"?

Tags: python, generator

I have a function which I want to yield bytes from (generator behaviour) and also write to a file (non-generator behaviour) depending on whether the `save` boolean is set. Is that possible?

```py
def encode_file(source, save=False, destination=None):
    # encode the contents of an input file 3 bytes at a time
    print('hello')
    with open(source, 'rb') as infile:
        # save bytes to destination file
        if save:
            print(f'saving to file {destination}')
            with open(destination, 'wb') as outfile:
                while (bytes_to_encode := infile.read(3)):
                    l = len(bytes_to_encode)
                    if l < 3:
                        bytes_to_encode += (b'\x00' * (3 - l))
                    outfile.write(bytes_to_encode)
            return
        # yield bytes to caller
        else:
            while (bytes_to_encode := infile.read(3)):
                l = len(bytes_to_encode)
                if l < 3:
                    bytes_to_encode += (b'\x00' * (3 - l)) # pad bits if short
                yield encode(bytes_to_encode)
            return
```

In the above implementation, the function always behaves as a generator. When I call

```py
encode_file('file.bin', save=True, destination='output.base64')
```

it does not print "hello" instead, it returns a generator object. This does not make sense to me. Shouldn't "hello" be printed and then shouldn't control be directed to the `if save:` portion of the code thus avoiding the part of the function that yields completely?

Comment: If skipping a `yield` made a function a non-generator, how would a generator produce an empty sequence?

Comment: Note that you could combine `save` and `destination`, letting the default `None` signify yielding the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can’t **be** a generator and also not be one, but of course you can decide whether to **return** a generator object or not by defining a helper function.  To avoid duplicating the (read) `with` between the two (and reduce redundancy in general), make one branch a **client** of the other:

```
def encode_file(source, save=False, destination=None):
    # encode the contents of an input file 3 bytes at a time
    print('hello')
    # save bytes to destination file
    if save:
        print(f'saving to file {destination}')
        with open(destination, 'wb') as outfile:
            for bytes_to_encode in encode_file(source):
                outfile.write(bytes_to_encode)
    # yield bytes to caller
    else:
        def g():
            with open(source, 'rb') as infile:
                while (bytes_to_encode := infile.read(3)):
                    l = len(bytes_to_encode)
                    if l < 3:
                        bytes_to_encode += (b'\x00' * (3 - l)) # pad bits if short
                    yield encode(bytes_to_encode)
        return g()
```

(Thanks to interjay for pointing out the need for the `with` in `g`.)

Comment: This will close the file before the data is read due to the `with` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a function generator on the fly, but you can extract the logic into a generator function and then create a separate function that will either return that generator or save it to a file. Here's a simpler example for demonstration purposess with comments:

```
# example function as a generator
# put all your logic here
def getNums_gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i


def getNums(n, asList=False):
    gen = getNums_gen(n)
    # if we don't want to save it, just return the generator
    if not asList:
        return gen

    # if we want to save it, loop through the generator and do whatever
    # is needed to save the data. in this example, we'll just save it as a
    # list, but it could be written to a file too
    lst = [num for num in gen]
    return lst


print(getNums(5, asList=True))
print(getNums(5, asList=False))
```